# Running a Ruby on Rails Application from GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm cloning a RoR app from Github. After the clone I install my gems. Now at this point my question/problem arises. Some research I've done suggests I do a

```
rake db:create
```

followed by a

```
rake db:migrate
```

I've tried both of those steps but am still having trouble.

When I run

```
rails console
```

and do something like Plan.first it returns nil. And when I try to visit my application I get an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in `PagesController#home` error alluding to the fact that it can't find the plan id of 1.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your case, the app is telling you that your database does not contain a record in the plans table with the id of 1. It sounds like you need to go through the Rails guide for beginnners.

Comment: Do `rake schema:load` then `rake db:seed`

Answer (score 3):

You have an empty database with no data in it, if seeds are provided - `rake db:seed` will help, otherwise you'll have to create initial data youself (in rails console, or may be directly in db)

Comment: Ah okay I think I'm starting to get it. Sorry, bit of a beginner =\. So when I cloned the app I got the database "set up", like the columns and rows of the database, but no data..In the case of the Plan table from the original app, there were two plans, which provide core functionality of the application. Is there a way to get the data from the database of the original app to the clone? If not - could I fix the original app to "tell" the database of a cloned app to start with certain data, being that it's critical to run the app. Again, new to all this - you guys are helping me learn!

Comment: If that data is not provided/publicly accessible - you cannot, think of it as of a truck loaded with something valuable: you can buy exactly the same model of truck, but it will not have the same load inside it